# Does Anyone Know how to do Typing using the SQLAlchemy 2.0 Select API?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, mypy, python-typing

Using the latest querying patterns from SQLAlchemy 2.0 (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html) and want to annotate my CRUD functions. I am using Python 3.11 and Mypy 1.4.0.

There is some [documentation on how to do typing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#whatsnew-20-expression-typing-examples) but it's not working for me.

There is [something](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#the-catch-all-stubs-must-be-uninstalled) in these docs about how all stubs must be uninstalled for typing to work but I don't seem to have any stubs installed.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy import Row, Sequence, Tuple

from app.models import User as UserDBModel

UserRow = Row[Tuple[UserDBModel]]

def get_users(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100) -> Sequence[UserRow]:
    return db.scalars(select(UserDBModel).offset(skip).limit(limit)).all()
```

For `UserRow` Mypy complains as follows: `Type argument "sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Tuple" of "Row" must be a subtype of "tuple[Any, ...]"  [type-var]mypy(error) Value of type variable "_TP" of "Row" cannot be "sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Tuple"  [type-var]mypy(error)`

But doing what it says doesn't work.

For the function return type, Mypy says the following: `Incompatible return value type (got "typing.Sequence[Row[tuple[User]]]", expected "sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Sequence")  [return-value]`. But if I replace the Sequence import with the one from that path, it makes the same complaint!

Am I doing something wrong? If I am not doing something wrong, has anyone got around these kind of errors? Or is the problem upstream of me and I should give up on explicit annotations for now?

Comment: what about `-> UserDBModal[]` instead of `-> Sequence[UserRow]` ?

Comment: That's how you would type it if I was still using the `query` API rather than the `select` API

Comment: Have you tried using `typing.Tuple` instead of `sqlalchemy.Tuple`?

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: After your edit, for me `mypy --strict` passes if the return type is of the function is `Sequence[User]`.

Comment: I think I've found the same but I'm pretty sure that's not the correct type annotation. I'd rather not annotate than use that

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out the correct annotation when using the above syntax is just `Sequence[User]` as https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb pointed out. I had misunderstood the docs when I first read them